# What can cause a Debug Assertion Error. Specifically, in my code

Tags: c++, debugging

I am working on writing a compiler for a school project, and this assignment calls for me to print the tokens of a text file to the console window. I want to make it clear I **do not** want my homework done for me.

I have been working with this stupid function that iterates through the file, and concatenates a char or a c-string value (my tutor was vague on this part of his instructions...) to a string variable named "token." I can work through the first line of the file fine, which is "main()", but when I try and access the next line I get 1 of two errors. The first is a string subscript out of range error, though I think this was because I was trying to access part of a string array that didn't exist. The most **prevalent** error I am getting is a debug assertion error:

> Debug Assertion Failed  Final.exe
>   File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\isctype.c Expression:
>   (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256

I have included my function and its associated header file. Nothing is going on in main except a function call. If at all possible, could you see what I am failing to see. I realize that my code structure is poor, I won't lie (I am in school after all). So, any comments, criticism, and suggestions are very welcome. And always,thank you for any and all time.

.CPP File (As it is now)

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <string>

    using namespace std; 

    void tokenWork::openFile()
    {
        fileName = "test.txt"; 

        source.open(fileName);

        if(!source.is_open())
        {
       cout << "Cannot find file " << endl; 
        }
    }

    void tokenWork::traveseLine()
    {

    pos = 0; 
    while (!source.eof())
    {  
          getline(source,myLine); 
          int length = myLine.length(); 
          letters = new char[length];
          myLine.copy(letters,length); 

          c = letters[pos]; 

          if (isalpha(c))
             token = token + myLine[pos]; 
          else if (isdigit(c))
             token = token + letters; 
          else 
          {
             cout << token << endl; 
             token = ""; 
          }

          if (c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '+' || c == '=' || myLine[pos] == '(' || c == ')' || c == ';')
                cout << myLine[pos] << endl;  
          c = letters[pos++]; 
    }
}
```

.h file

```
    #ifndef H_LEX
    #define H_LEX

    #include <string> 
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <fstream> 

    using namespace std; 

    class tokenWork
    {
    public: 
    std::string fileName; 
    std::string myLine; 
    std::string token; 

    int pos; 
    int length; 
    int c;

    char *letters; 

    ifstream source; 

    void openFile(); 
    void traveseLine(); 
    void closeFile(); 

};

    #endif
```

Comment: My suggestion is to learn to use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint in your function and debug through it to see exactly what's causing the error.

Comment: What is this line doing? if (c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '+' || c == '=' || myLine[pos] == '(' || c == ')' || c == ';').

Comment: Could you provide your two-line input?

Comment: Please disregard this post. Thanks to any who looked at it!

Answer (score 2):

That debug assertion error originates from the call to `std::isalpha/isdigit` when you pass it an argument with a value > 255, which is the maximum value the type `char` (which you should probably be using instead of `int` here) can hold. I can't tell you the exact origin though as you don't provide the source file, but you should be able to figure it out yourself quite easily: run the program under the debugger, it will break at the assert. Move up in the call stack and inspect the values of your variables, that should give you a clue.

a couple of tips:

- you're using c++ here, no need for using raw char arrays. Use std::string instead.
- don't put using namepsace std; in header files: everything incuding that file will import the entire std namespace
- if you include  in a header, you don't have t include it again in the source file
- learn to use the debugger, it's an invaluable tool and will aid you in learning why something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the tokens on each given line, I'm exceedingly confused by all the extra work you're doing.  Shrinking your function down (and a small change) should get you a start:

```
// note, poorly named function, it traverses the whole file
void tokenWork::traveseLine()
{

pos = 0; 
while (!source.eof())
{  
   getline(source,myLine); 

   int len = myLine.size();

   // NOTE: This was missing from your code, it traverses the line
   //       that was read in with getline() above.
   for(int x = 0; x < len; ++x)
   {
       // NOTE: This is (in my opinion) a slightly more readable
       //       version of your if() statement above on tokens
       //       It doesn't have all your tokens, additional ones
       //       can be added by adding a case for them above the 
       //       line that prints them out.  Since there is no break
       //       statement, the functionality for all the cases above 
       //       fall through so they all get printed out.
       switch(myLine[x])
       {
          case '{':
          case '}':
          case '+':
          case '=':
          // add additional tokens as case statements as necessary
            cout << myLine[x] << endl;  // print it out
            break;
          default:   // not a token
            break;  
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: this looks good, but please use size_t to store myLine.size() (compiler will complain for 64 bit platforms, with reason) or better yet const size_t

Comment: True enough -- was aiming for a comfort level with the OP, and didn't want to through too many types (that likely haven't been seen yet) at them.  Note if len is changed to size_t, x in the for loop should be as well.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to

```
#include <cctype>
```

in order to use isdigit() and isalpha()

and this

```
c = letters[pos++];
```

looks like the source of a bug.  pos always increments, but does it ever stop? what happens if it gets to the last character (letters.length()-1) and you hit this line: increments? array out of bounds I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to point at particular place in the code - it has so many problems...

The error you see most probably results from

```
token = token + letters;
```

letters is not null-terminated (string::copy does not provide null-termination, and you do not reserve a space for null anyway), so `+` operator falls off the end and encounters something nasty.

Besides that, it looks like you increment `pos` about once per `getline` and never reset it. Your code looks like there should have been an inner loop, but I don't see any.